# How to get a block with NBT on xbox?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have tried to use pick block on xbox but it will not get the data saved for what I pick even with other buttons.

Comment: I don't think this is possible currently in bedrock edition. Have you tried holding the sprint button at the same time as the pick block button?

Comment: Yes I have but it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a block with data to place myself?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374589/how-do-i-get-a-block-with-data-to-place-myself)

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to connect a keyboard or have a player with a PC join,  maybe there is some way to have your controller configured like a keyboard though.