# How do I get a block with data to place myself?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

*Are you looking for how to use `/setblock` with blocks with data? See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374633/250180).*

---

How do I get a block with data in my inventory so I can place it myself? In Java Edition, these commands work:

```
give @s chest{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:"diamond",count:10b}]}}
give @s sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"foo\",\"bold\":true}"}}
```

How can I do this in Bedrock Edition, where there is no access to NBT tags from commands?

---

[Browse more workarounds for using NBT in Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Computers

You can do this with the “pick block” control, which defaults to the middle mouse button. Put your crosshair over the block you want to get and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + pick block, which will put that block with its data into your inventory. Of course, this will only work in creative mode.

## Touch devices

Unfortunately, this cannot be done on touch devices without “Full Keyboard Gameplay” enabled, as there is no “pick block” control.

## Consoles

Consoles do not have the pick block control assigned by default, and it will have to be configured in the settings window.

For more information on the “pick block” control, see [Controls](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls#Bedrock_Edition) on the Minecraft wiki.

Comment: As of 1.19.10, keyboard and mouse controls are now fully implemented on iOS and iPadOS, so CTRL + Pick Block should now be possible on those devices.

Answer (score 0):

This IS actually possible on all console editions (not exactly sure about pocket edition though). What you do, is go over to settings, then controls, and find "Pick Block". Select any button that you would like for it to be (I chose left on the D-Pad). Then, go to the command block you would like to copy, and press left on the d-pad (or whatever you set it to) and you should get an exact replica of the command block you copied!

NOTE: I am aware that someone HAS already done an explanation of the pick block, but im just showing you how to do it on the bedrock edition of Minecraft. (For console players.)

Comment: This info was already conveyed in the previous answer. The other answer was also for Bedrock Edition too, so your claim that your answer was the only MCBE answer there was incorrect.