# How do i get barrels pre loaded with items on Minecraft bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I saw this on a server i was playing on and wanted to implement it on to my realm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give a player an item with custom properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374643/how-do-i-give-a-player-an-item-with-custom-properties)

Comment: @pppery I would say it's a duplicate of [How do I get a block with data to place myself?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374589/how-do-i-get-a-block-with-data-to-place-myself), since I believe OP is asking about obtaining a filled container.

Comment: Agreed, that would definitely be a better duplicate. Probably not worth bothering a moderator to fix the problem, though.

Answer (score -1):

On java, you would simply merge a "LootTable" string with the data: "minecraft:chests/end_city_treasure" to the chest in the structure NBT.

I am not familiar with bedrock datapacks but if they use nbt structures I assume the answer is similar.